# Is there a selector for 2 or more elements with the same attribute value?

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-selectors

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

```
.standard {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.standard.color-0 + .standard.color-0,
.standard.color-1 + .standard.color-1,
.standard.color-2 + .standard.color-2,
.standard.color-3 + .standard.color-3,
.standard.color-4 + .standard.color-4,
.standard.color-5 + .standard.color-5,
.standard.color-6 + .standard.color-6,
.standard.color-7 + .standard.color-7,
.standard.color-8 + .standard.color-8 {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Is there perhaps some selector that checks for matches of the classes found on 2 or more elements without actually knowing the exact class's name? Such as something like:

```
.standard.color-* + .standard.color-* {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

What I have currently (posted above) works the way I want it to as far as how it displays on my site, but I am just curious whether, or not, I am doomed to constantly add `.standard.color-# + .standard.color-#` for every new color I need (which in for this case are background-colors for full-width `<section>` tags).

Examples:

```
<section class="standard color-0"></section> // top and bottom padding
<section class="standard color-1"></section> // top and bottom padding

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

<section class="standard color-1"></section> // top and bottom padding
<section class="standard color-1"></section> // padding-top: 0; (if both "color-#" is the exact same this loses its top padding)
```

EDIT: Simplified post and code. `<section>` will always have a `.standard` class and a `.color-` class with `.color-0` being `background-color: transparent;`.

Comment: There isn’t a way to do that, no.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, due to the static nature of selectors, CSS doesn't offer a way for one compound selector to reference any part of another compound selector, not even with [a regex-like syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593098/how-can-i-use-emulate-regex-like-backreferences-in-css-selectors). So you can't, for example, match an element with the same class name or attribute value as its previous sibling without hardcoding the actual value, in both compound selectors. The only solution is the one you have.

As I mention in my answer to the question linked above, if you're using a preprocessor, you can automate this somewhat. It will still result in the same hardcoded selectors in CSS, but the task of actually writing those selectors is offloaded to the preprocessor instead. Here's an example using SCSS:

```
.standard {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;

  &%consecutive {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  // To accommodate more numbered classes simply edit this loop
  @for $i from 0 through 8 {
    &.color-#{$i} + &.color-#{$i} {
      @extend %consecutive;
    }
  }
}
```

This, again, requires knowing the values in advance. If you cannot write down all the possible values (or you don't want to), you'll need to write a script to examine the values in runtime.

Comment: I am using `!important` because I have the padding of the `.standard` class set to different values at various browser sizes (media queries) and I did not want to have this `padding-top` killing rule in more places than one.

Comment: @spunge: The added specificity of your selectors will ensure they will override any `.standard` rules regardless of media queries. But if you want to be safe, I guess it's fine to leave it in. Try not to overuse it.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your most recent comment edit. I completely overlooked using `.standard.color-#`. I will fix this in my stylesheet now.