# Can one use :nth-child to select elements where n is equal to n of a different element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Would it be possible to write CSS to select elements where their *n* is equal to the *n* of another element in the same selector:

```
input:nth-child(1):checked ~ div > div:nth-child(1)
input:nth-child(2):checked ~ div > div:nth-child(2)
input:nth-child(3):checked ~ div > div:nth-child(3)
...
input:nth-child(n):checked ~ div > div:nth-child(n)
```

Does CSS support this capability, or would everything have to be written out line-by-line?

Comment: No. You can't relate to the first seleted `n` with second `n`

Comment: update your logic, put the input next to the divs and you can use  `+` instead of `~` then consider label to place the *visual clickable* element where you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors doesn't support variables or backreferences of any kind, in either attribute selectors ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593098/how-can-i-use-emulate-regex-like-backreferences-in-attribute-selectors) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664025/is-there-a-selector-for-2-or-more-elements-with-the-same-attribute-value)) or functional pseudo-classes such as `:nth-child()`. You [cannot use custom properties in selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951877/is-it-possible-to-use-css-vars-in-css3-selectors) either.

As with attribute selectors in the first two links above, you can use a preprocessor to automate this but the resulting CSS file will still contain a hardcoded list of all the possibilities.