# CSS selector equivalent for xpath selector

Tags: xml, xpath, css-selectors

I'm quit new to CSS selector and I need to construct CSS selector that will look for row (items with same `r=''`) in html, where in first column value is `x1` and column `n` value is `x3`
For the purpose I got xpath `//cell[@c='0'][@val='x1'][@r=following::cell[@val='x3']/@r]`

Simplified xml equivalent

```html
<r>
  <cell c='0' r='0' val='x1'/>
  <cell c='1' r='0' val='x1'/>
  <cell c='2' r='0' val='x1'/>

  <cell c='0' r='1' val='x1'/>
  <cell c='1' r='1' val='y1'/>
  <cell c='2' r='1' val='y1'/>

  <cell c='0' r='2' val='x1'/>
  <cell c='1' r='2' val='x3'/>
  <cell c='2' r='2' val='x3'/>
</r>
```

Could someone suggest CSS selector that solves the task?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible in pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a CSS selector equivalent for

1. [referencing attribute values across different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593098/how-can-i-use-emulate-regex-like-backreferences-in-attribute-selectors/23594233#23594233)
2. the `following::` axis